# Open resource XML as String or InputString to give it to Xml.parse(...)

Tags: android

I'm working in a little app that needs to parse an XML file. The "parsing part" it's working great, everything goes fine...

But I'm having a little problem, I don't know how to open the resource that is under (res/xml/file.xml) to the Xml.parse(STRING, root.getContentHandler()); or Xml.parse (INPUTSTREAM...)...

The question is that I don't know how to get an InpuntStream or String from a xml file that is in the res folder... any idea?? I've googled it but all the examples in the web are from a web xml that is downloaded using http, but none of them show how to parse a file from the resources!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your XML file in `res/raw` instead of `res/xml`. Then:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.testXML)
```

will return an `InputStream` you can use with `Xml.parse()`.